# Yang-Mills massive ghosts

Tags: lagrangian-formalism, mass, gauge-theory, yang-mills, ghosts

Is there any procedure to add a mass to Faddeev-Popov Lagrangian density of a pure Yang-Mills theory, other than just add it from nowhere?

Comment: Is there a reason you would want to have massive ghosts?

Comment: Yes, through a method and some assumptions I obtained a sum of massive propagators from the free term and the quadratic terms alone (just like one obtains the propagator from the free field theory, ignoring the other terms from the lagrangian density). The problem is that for one loop amplitude, the remaining loops for the self-energy are 3-gluon loop and the ghost loop. So I want massive ghosts to have the same prefactor before $p^\mu p^\nu -\eta^{ \mu \nu }p^2$.